# How can I use "is" to determine if the value of a parameter is a type of class?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to test if the current page of my application is the CardsTabPage like this:

```
_page.CurrentPage is Japanese.CardsTabPage
```

However it always returns false even though when I use the debugger it seems like it should read true.  Here's what I see when I hover over CurrentPage:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong and why this:

[image]

is not returning true?

I also tried this but it doesn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access `_page.CurrentPage.CurrentPage`, but you can't do that directly because the compile-time type of `_page.CurrentPage` is just `Page`. You need to first cast that to `NavigationPage`, then use the `CurrentPage` property of that.

If your compiler supports pattern matching, you can do that as:

```
if (_page.CurrentPage is NavigationPage np && np.CurrentPage is Japanese.CardsTabPage)
```

Otherwise you'd need something like:

```
if (_page.CurrentPage is NavigationPage &&
    ((NavigationPage) _page.CurrentPage).CurrentPage is Japanese.CardsTabPage)
```